# Convert adobe acrobat PDF to normal PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion, adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF file that can only be opened with Adobe Acrobat DC. When I try to open it with chrome for example I see the message below. How can I convert this PDF file to a normal pdf file so that I can open it with other PDF viewer apps?

```
Please wait...

If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF
viewer may not be able to display this type of document.

You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or Linux® by
visiting http://www.adobe.com/go/reader_download.

For more assistance with Adobe Reader visit http://www.adobe.com/go/acrreader.
```

Answer (score 2):

The official answer is

1. ask the Author of that document to publish as a PDF/A compatible document (that will enforce it to be) a Universally Acceptable Accessible PDF Archive format
2. attempt to determine which non PDF format Adobe are using, as not all of their proprietary formats can simply be converted by reprinting. If it is Dynamic XFA then you have no choice but to ask the Author to rebuild as an accessible PDF since reprinting cannot allow for dynamic entries.

Basically if it can be fully used without problems in an XFA reader like Chrome or FireFox you may be able to use that to reprint but all 3 renders can appear different, so then that means none are PDF, as PDF should not vary from method to method (the concept is all VALID PDFs should look the same whatever the rendering method).

Bottom line, ONLY the Source Author can potentially (depending on their skill) output a valid replacement PDF.

IF we attempt to print or copy paste or dumb convert the XFA contents we just get the dumb graphics.

The XFA is only a skin for the task of emailing forms data as seen on the left. Thus the closest we can get to non Adobe behaviours, is to convert the specialist proprietary form from XFA to AcroForm which can also store and process the FDF data fields.

There are many such converters, with different abilities, but the closer to Live Cycle regeneration and cost the better they are likely to perform across the board. see the "Converted" form lower right.

[image]

Once converted from Dynamic or Static XFA to NON-XFA the form is instantly reusable as an AcroForm FDF carrier and the submit action can be reinstated as required
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this method requires Adobe Acrobat DC. Don't forget to uncheck McCafee antivirus in the installation. Open you PDF file with Adobe Acrobat than click on to printer icon and select "Microsoft Print to PDF" as printer. Then select print. After that it will ask you where you want to save the files. Select a folder and save it. Now you can open the new file with any normal PDF viewer app for example google chrome.